# How do I avoid Mocking the IEventAggregator when Integration Testing with c# and MVVM?

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, mvvm, integration

I am integration testing and I want to test without Mocking because I want an end to end to of the wcf service, database etc. My code is below and where I have a comment that says Mocking I need to know what to do instead of Mocking? This code runs but gives an error "{"Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."}". How can I fix that error? BTW I have seen a similar question but no accepted answer (I would not have accepted the answer on that question either).

```
namespace Optimal.SynTQ.Client.Shell.Services.Proxies.Tests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MyProxyTests
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class IntegrationTestMyClassProxy
    {
        #region Test Initialisation

        private MyServiceModel _serviceModel;
        private MyFilterServiceModel _filteredServiceModel;
        //private IMyProxy _MyProxy;
        private MyProxy _MyProxy;
        private ProxyInvoker _proxyInvoker;
        private int _counter;
        private IEnumerable<MyServiceModel> _list;
        private ImpersonationFactory _impersonationFactory;
        private IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
        private UnityContainer _unityCont;
        private EndpointManager _endpointManager;
        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        private EventAggregator _eventAgg;
        //private ILog _log;
        private ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(IntegrationTestMyProxy));
        //private Logging.SynTQLogger.Log _log;

        PagedListServiceModel<MyViewModel> _mappedPolicies = null;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            BasicConfigurator.Configure();

            _endpointManager = new EndpointManager();
            _eventAggregator = Substitute.For<IEventAggregator>();        //Mocking

            //register unity container then resolve
            _unityCont = new UnityContainer();
            _unityCont.RegisterType<MyProxy>();

            _impersonationFactory = new ImpersonationFactory(_unityCont);
            _proxyInvoker = new ProxyInvoker(_impersonationFactory, _endpointManager, _unityCont, _eventAggregator, _log);

            _unityCont.RegisterType<ConfigurationStore, ConfigurationStore>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ITypeMapFactory), MapperRegistry.Mappers));
            _unityCont.RegisterType<IConfigurationProvider, ConfigurationStore>();
            _unityCont.RegisterType<IConfiguration, ConfigurationStore>();
            _unityCont.RegisterType<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IConfigurationProvider)));
            _unityCont.RegisterType<ITypeMapFactory, TypeMapFactory>();

            StaticMapper.CreateAutoMapperMappingsFromAttribute(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyViewModel)));
        }

        #endregion

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestAuditGetFilteredMyDefaultDates()
        {
            //Arrange
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("myServerPort", "808");
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("myServerMachineName", "localhost");
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("myServerMyAddress", "net.tcp://{0}:{1}/Blah.BlahBlah.MyServer.MyServices/MyService.svc");
            var request = Substitute.For<ConfigurationRequest>();

            //Act
            MyProxy _MyProxy = new MyProxy(_proxyInvoker);
            MyViewModel MyViewModel = new MyViewModel(_MyProxy);

            MyFilterServiceModel filter = Mapper.Map<MyFilterServiceModel>(MyViewModel);

            var results = _MyProxy.GetFilteredMy(filter);
        }
    }
}
```